# Implementing backprop in numpy

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I a trying to implement backprop in numpy by defining a function that performs some kind operation given an input, weight matrix and bias, and returns the output with the backward function, which can be used to update weights.

Currently this is my [code](https://topaz.github.io/paste/#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) , however I think there are some bugs in the derivation, as the gradients for the W1 matrix are too large. Here is a pytorch implementation for the same thing as a reference [torch](https://topaz.github.io/paste/#XQAAAQBmAwAAAAAAAAA0m0pnuFI8c/sCK29YBEimQjBsJ09JcUCsfpJuf+Z0kA4xajm93naJjsM3EZ1GHXlxWzt7zkVBFYEmR0PDoXAfsVGHGjlx1SlTTZZ3e9A8aXdI3JAfK6WChdnAiHWja8B9XgBGRf3pNq30zgmpusTdIEUVe7Lnd5SUyA2FE0h1cX62Vw6LxXH//9vkAo6ONbF8WKs/X0x6j9SrmgAxUdjFPVqMVn7djocn/iAhqAbDwGfVR+j4sCiy+zQ6bkgzScbohGgmFxcAy0zFVAYMHk4UzkCo62z7Ej5wkaPLPRH1a7JEW/vyrp5uNX2CCA7LSfMMQm5tSgi9X9Lc2LMM6Whr0ysFCVZLBYBhGMmWx+B07i3XELrjEN2uKJZK2R5c9Y0GZ2b9+T0HQA==).

Any help is appreciated.